# How to interrupt long R command

Tags: r

I sometimes have a large data set loaded in `R`. Sometimes I accidentally just type the name of the data set and hit enter. Then the R prompt goes blind and becomes irresponsive.

How can I interrupt the call to the full data set without killing R itself?

Comment: Rstudio has a `stop` button

Comment: Except that it doesn't always work, from my experience

Comment: @Michael, everything has it's limits. I don't think there is any better way